# 0365 Authentication .NET CORE

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, office365api, http-token-authentication

I am aware of Azure Active Directory, but not sure where to start.. or if it's the best option.

I have a .NET core App (deployed to Azure WebApp). I want to secure this app with o365 auth. When the person has logged in, I need to be able to track each request to the API based on a token.

I'm not sure if this is as simple as it sounds on- is it?

Thank you.

Comment: It is very easy to Authenticate a user against Azure AD. When you start a new project you can select Azure AD as the authentication type and it wires it all up, you just have to provide your specific app registration details - client id, tenant, etc. But that is a separate issue from tracking based on a token. You might consider asking two questions.

Comment: I don't HAVE to track it with a token, but I need some kind of way to be able to track the requests too and from the Controller - any suggestions?

Comment: "Track Requests" is vague. What specifically do you want to track? If you add Application Insights to your app you will automatically get request tracing but I don't know if that is what you want. Your question is too vague and too broad to answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Let me try and clarify; I have a multi-tenant App. I need to know WHO is hitting the end point, and their access rights etc.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to answer my own question.
Assuming the person has Authenticated w/ O365:

```
var identity = ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity);
var name = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
var email = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name")?.Value;
```